# Python не видит telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Установил стандартную библиотеку pyTelegramBotAPI и python не видит её.

Писал программу сам, использовал код из документации и результат один и тот же:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "C:\Users\home\Desktop\телеграм боты\bot.py", 
line 1, in <module> import telebot ModuleNotFoundError: 
No module named 'telebot'
```

Пишу на Thonny.

Подскажите в чём может быть проблема. 
Буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте удалить библиотеку telebot( pip uninstall telebot ) и pip uninstall pyTelegramBotAPI, а затем заного pip install pyTelegramBotAPI, у меня была такая ситуация, просто этот модуль мешался установке и использованию pyTelegramBotAPI

Comment: к сожалению не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Я решил свою проблему
оказалось что Thonny имел свою версию python из за чего установленная мною библиотека на одной версии не отображалась на другой

всем спасибо за помощь.